# Refresh Icon Cache Without Rebooting

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, icons, cache

Normally, to refresh the icon cache in Windows, we have to reboot.

Is there a way to refresh the icon cache in Windows 7/8 **without rebooting**?

Comment: What have you tried? What happened? Why do you need it done? Are you talking about on Windows Explorer, Start Menu, task bar, where? Need more information

Comment: Yes I did... And that's why I'm asking for clarification. I saw this in the review queue, so I only read the answers now, but remember that this site is meant to also help visitors from Google or other search engines, as well

Comment: Normally, when we refresh the icon cache in Windows, we have to reboot, but my question and answer does it without a reboot.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Found this Q via Google in December 2017.  Thanks for posting this.  I liked the answer where it says to make the short batch file.  So in the comments I included the process of doing so.  Now my Win8.1 icons are fixed.  THANK YOU.  EXCELLENT QUESTION.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

**Yes.**

You can just run the following command to clear the icon cache:

```
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
```

For Windows 10, use:

```
ie4uinit.exe -show
```

[image]

Check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSDI1MlR3fM) for a demo.

[[tip credit]](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/refresh-icon-cache-windows-7-quickly/)

Comment: Does not work on Windows 8.1. You have to delete IconCache.db as explained by @Techie007.

Comment: @HelgeKlein it doesn't come with IE10... so only pre-IE10 OS'es have it. This includes Windows 7.

Comment: Definately doesn't work on 8.1. It runs but it doesn't clear the icon cache.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me in Windows 7

Comment: working on windows 7 Pro

Comment: For Windows 10, use the argument "show", mentioned in the same page (tip credit).

Comment: If you want to refresh notification icons too you can use this app : https://github.com/crazy-max/IconsRefresh

Comment: @Crazy Is it just a 1 liner? `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: @Elmo Yes it is !

Comment: Does **not** work on Windows 8.1. Sorry.

Comment: It didn't work for me in Win 7 (though it seemed to make a refresh) but the kill-explorer-etc thing did.

Comment: `ie4uinit.exe -show` worked for me in Windows 10, thanks!  So much easier than most of the tutorials telling you to go around deleting a bunch of .db files!

Comment: If you're fancy you can send the 'SHChange' notification with PowerShell too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818826/273668

Comment: Did not work for me with Win 10 Home 1909. The icons are still missing for some items in the start menu.

Comment: There is no ie4unit.exe on Windows 7.

Comment: This sometimes work and sometimes not. Usually after 3 minutes it loads the correct icon, but not immediately. (Win10)

Comment: Doesn't work: Windows 10

Comment: I had to restart Windows Explorer after running `ie4uinit.exe -show`, but after that, all the icons were back.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thank you!

Answer (score 57):

The following way has worked since Vista;  It requires an Explorer restart, but no reboot.

**Short version**: Stop all `explorer.exe` instances, delete the user's hidden `IconCache.db` file, and restart Explorer.

**Long Version** (there are other ways as well):

1. Close all Explorer windows that are currently open.
2. Launch *Task Manager* using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> key sequence, or by running `taskmgr.exe`.
3. In the *Process tab*, right-click on the `explorer.exe` process and select *End Process*.
4. Click the *End process* button when asked for confirmation.
5. From the *File* menu of *Task Manager*, select *New Task (Run…)*
6. Type `CMD.EXE`, and click OK
7. In the Command Prompt window, type the commands one by one and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after each command:

   ```
   CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
   DEL IconCache.db /a
   EXIT
   ```
8. In *Task Manager*, click *File*, select *New Task (Run…)*
9. Type `EXPLORER.EXE`, and click OK.

[instruction steps source](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-rebuild-the-icon-cache-in-windows-vista/)

**Warning**: It's important that **Explorer.exe** not be running when you delete the IconCache.db file. If explorer is running, it will simply write out the current (corrupt) icons the next time it is shut down (e.g. when you logoff, shutdown, or restart).

Comment: Awesome, it works for every windows icon, even configuration ones. Other methods only reset iconcs from files and folders

Comment: What I noticed lately is that the IconCache.db often not necessarily exists, but just restarting explorer.exe as described above solves the problem, too.

Comment: This answer deserves all the upvotes and the accepted tick IMO

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: You can use `%localappdata%` instead of `%userprofile%\AppData\Local`

Answer (score 28):

1. Open command console with admin privileges
2. `taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F`
3. `CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local`
4. `DEL IconCache.db /a`
5. start `explorer.exe` via *Task Manager*

Comment: worked for me, Win 8.1

Comment: This worked for me with Win 10 Home 1909, while the accepted answer does not.

Comment: It stopped working after I closed the command console. The icons disappeared again. Tried it again, IconCache.db not found and more icons disappeared.

Comment: Note for those who are NOT running Win10 as admin... these instructions will delete the icons for your admin user, not a standard user.

Answer (score 12):

Create a .bat file and paste the following lines in it and then run it.

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
del IconCache.db /a
start explorer.exe
```

Comment: That's cool.  Works fine in Win8.1 Quick and easy.  And with the "QuickEdit" and "Run as Administrator" settings in the taskbar CMD icon, I was able to create the bat file by simply copying your text above, then clicking on the CMD icon.  Typed `copy con clearcache.bat` then Enter, then Right-click to paste it in.  One more Enter then a Ctrl-Z finishes the job of creating the file.  Then I typed `clearcache` to run it.  WIndows blinked and all the icons came back fixed.  Took a total of 30 seconds for the whole fix.  THANK YOU.  EXCELLENT ANSWER.

Answer (score 8):

There's a clean way to close the `Explorer.exe` instance which shows the taskbar and the Desktop icons.

You have to popup the classic `Shutdown` dialog window. The only common way I found to accomplish this is:

1. Leave at least one pixel of Desktop background free of overlapping Windows, then click on it to focus on the Desktop itself (the one with the icons).
2. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> keyboard shortcut: then the classic Shutdown dialog will appear.
3. Now, press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> **and** click on `Cancel`.

Comment: Why does this work? What does CTRL+ALT+SHIFT click on Cancel do?

Comment: Also this: open the Windows 7 start menu, hold Ctrl-Shift down and right click in the empty space above the Shutdown/Logoff/Restart button (whichever you have configured as the default). A menu appears with "Exit Explorer" as an option. Click it and Explorer terminates.

Comment: If you use the Windows 7 startmenu trick it's important to make sure you close ALL `File Explorer` windows first!  Then you can `Exit Explorer` from the Windows 7 start menu.  First open command prompt.  Next click on the start menu, hold `Ctrl+Shift` and right click right above the `Shutdown` button to expose the `Exit Explorer` sub menu option and click it.  In the command prompt, type `CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local` then type `del IconCache.db /a` and last type `explorer`.

Comment: To get your start menu back, ctrl+alt+del then file: new task and enter `explorer.exe`

Comment: Press `Win` and release it. Then **twice** `Alt+F4`. This way is faster and you needn't to see part of the Desktop to open the classic shutdown menu.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to make a `.bat`, copy the line behind, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, paste it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
cmd /c taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & del /a %userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db & start explorer
```

You can also paste it in the address bar of an explorer window; and, of course, in a command line window (you don't need the `cmd /c` then) but you won't have the line to easily repeat it in case you need it again.

**CAVEAT**:

Don't run this line in an elevated prompt unless you're sure you are the only user in the system or you will kill explorer **in all open sessions**. Therefore, don't press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the *Run* dialog box.

By the way, I don't see the need of the `cd /d` command I see repeatedly. It seems everybody just copy/paste without considering what are the commands for.

Note:

I use `&` instead of `&&` just in case one of the commands fails, to ensure explorer is restarted.

Answer (score 2):

Though not a userland answer, simple call to

```
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, NULL, NULL);
```

does that [1]. Possibly someone would create an utility to do just that; currently, using 7-zip and trying to modify file associations (for all users; without elevating permissions; which would fail and tell that operation failed) calls the notifications and rebuilds the icon cache.

Oh, just saw the comments to the accepted answer, where the call is discussed, and a tool for that is mentioned: https://github.com/crazy-max/IconsRefresh.

[1] https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify

Answer (score 2):

`ie4uinit.exe` as suggested by Elmo is a good option because it is available on every system already. I had trouble with it not refreshing sometimes in a complex batch file I have. [Nircmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) is a great alternative that worked for me.

This is the command I used that worked: `nircmd shellrefresh`

Comment: I also had the problem that `ie4uinit.exe` didn't always refresh. I tried Nircmd as well and still no solid success. (sometimes works sometimes not)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete refreshed icon cache, go to the addressbar of windows explorer and type "C:\Users*Username*\AppData\Local" and then delete IconCache.db.

**Note:**It may be a hidden file. So I recommend turning Show Hidden Files on in Folder Option.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score -3):

Not very beautiful but effective:

C:> tskill explorer

Comment: That's not enough. You have to delete the icon cache db as well. In any case killing explorer is already covered by the other answers.