# Change program icon in Win7 notification area

Tags: windows-7, icons, notification-area

I want to totally change my win7 DE to black and white. I've managed to replace icons in pinned icons, and standart win7 notifications are great, but for custom programs the icons are colored

[image].

I think I need to replace icon resources in *.exe. But after replacing resource icon for Clip2Net (first icon in notification area) it is still colored, while in explorer it showns grayed. Of course I've restarted explorer.exe, and when it didn't help I've rebooted my machine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After ensuring that *all* icons in the EXE/DLL etc. have been suitably edited, did you try [refreshing the icon cache](http://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are changing the wrong icon set. For each icon there is about five of them, all at different resolutions. As the icons in the notification are very small, they use one of the smaller resolutions. If you use reshacker you will be able to change the different icons.

Edit #1: If you go changing the size of the icons in explorer (the view) you should see the icons change colour.

Edit #2: I notice that chrome worked. What you could to is right click on the icons in the taskbar (the main icons) and do it again on the icons name then select properties and change it there. As to the icons is the notification area, you could just hide them.

Edit #3: Sorry, the above it a mistake. What you have to do is create a shorcut, then change the icon, the drag it to the taskbar. You can then delete the shorcut on your desktop.

Comment: There is only one icon in exe: http://clip2net.com/s/2HmWW

Comment: Have you tried any other applications? And has the taskbar icon changed for Clip2Net? If it has, it could be that the computer needs a restart to actualize the notification area.

Comment: Yes, I've restarted my computer. Other icons are not working too.

Comment: @madhead please see my edit

Comment: Edit#2 and Edit#3 are working for pinned tabs only. If I run any other application and change its icon it is valid only till application restart.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's correct. You could try looking and seeing if the application has more than one exe.