# Why the shortcuts on desktop may be repainted at startup of Win 7?

Tags: boot, desktop, file-shortcut

At boot or startup of Windows 7, all of my shortcuts appear correct on the desktop, but after a few seconds they will change to white pages, and are then repainted with their original design. This is a visual annoyance. It is possible to avoid this 'repaint'?

Comment: I've also noted that this happens to applications pinned to the task bar.

Comment: Try [refreshing the icon cache](http://superuser.com/q/499078/289138).