# Windows 7 explorer won't refresh favicon (.ico) thumbnail

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, thumbnails, favicon

Windows 7 - I have a folder on my computer which was copied from another location. It contains a .ico file and some other .png files.

After copying the directory, I overwrote all the files with new ones but with the same names. All the .png file thumbnails have changed and are showing the new image, but the .ico file refuses to change from what it used to be.

I tried these things. Nothing worked:

- Refreshing windows explorer
- Deleting the .ico and saving a new one with the same name
- Disk cleanup to delete thumbnails
- Restart windows explorer

The .ico needs to have the same name `favicon.ico` as before.

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/a/499079/50173

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally figured out a fix.

- Right click the file, "Open With", "Choose Another App", **Windows Photo Viewer**, "Always use this app to open .ico files", "OK"
- Right click the file, "Open With", "Choose Another App", **Visual Studio 2013**, "Always use this app to open .ico files", "OK"

Maybe other combinations of programs will work? I think the trick is that Windows Photo VIewer tries to give the file a generic icon whereas Visual Studio tries to give the file *itself* as an icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `IconCache.db`, and/or `Thumbs.db`

You may have to disable `Hide Protected Operating Systems Files` from Folder Options > View > Hide Protected Operating Systems Files

Comment: There is no `Thumbs.db` or `IconCache.db` in the directory, even when showing protected OS files.