# Alt-Tab Thumbnails Broken Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am currently having the problem of when I Alt-Tab or go into the task view, the thumbnail for each program looks as if it corrupt. Has anybody seen this before and has a solution? This is the only problem that I have that I can see, but it is still mildly annoying and worrying. Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: What exactly is wrong in the screenshot?

Comment: @Ramhound took me a couple looks to spot it as well. The program Icons in the title headers are whacky.

Comment: @NickP What have you attempted to repair it already? Rebooted yet? Have you tried [clearing the icon cache](http://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting)?

Comment: I haven't tried rebooting yet, as I need to do other work, and it is only a minor inconvenience. Tried clearing the icon cache, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 after a reboot I still have the same problem. Don't see anything else wrong with the system though.