# What is this double blue arrow icon overlay?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons, overlay

This is a duplicate of [Two blue arrows at top right of icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons).

I'm in the process of recovering from a major data-loss disaster. After restoring files from my external hard drive, many of the folders and files have a new (to me) icon overlay on them. The icons appear in Windows Explorer and in the file/folder property dialogs.

The icon overlay shows two blue arrows facing each other.

**What do these icon overlays mean?**

I am running Windows 10 Pro (64-bit).

[image: Up-close view of icon overlay]

[image: Properties Dialogs with Icon Overlays]

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons) .. I had to search for `double arrow facing each other icon` to find it but it looks similar to what your seeing (same icons at least)

Comment: Ah, thanks, @txtechhelp. My search fu is no match for vague icon overlays.

Comment: Since I couldn't find it using search, maybe this question should stick around so that people can find it.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree to the 'finding' thought since this issue is not completely intuitive (nor is the other question answered).