# What is this icon appearing on my desktop icons?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, icons

I have noticed that a few of the desktop icons have an "overlay icon" that looks like 2 blue arrows pointing toward each other in the top right hand corner of the icon.

[image: Icon Overlay]

There is no relation between the programs that have this icon, except perhaps that they are using a network connection to databases (MySQL and MSSQL). I am using Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Do you use Norton 360? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/blue-double-arrows/6febdedb-e0f3-4c36-88bd-83a76dda7f63?db=5&auth=1

Comment: No, we are currently using Webroot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two blue arrows at top right of icons](http://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This overlayed icon is to show that the files have been compressed.  Right click an icon, go to Advanced Attributes and uncheck the `Compress contents to save disk space` box.

If the files are not compressed but still show the icon then it is probably a glitch.

You can read about a similar issue here that solves the question: http://www.tenforums.com/customization/26212-new-double-blue-arrows-shortcut-overlay-2.html

Comment: Is there any downside to these files being compressed?

Comment: Compressed files save disk space at the expense of launch speed, so there is a potential downside there.  However since the icons are shortcuts, which take up about 4KB, you are probably not saving any space by having them compressed.  I would uncompress them.

Comment: The programs that those shortcuts point to may have been compressed... or the entire Program files or Program Files (x86) and sub-folders. The shortcut icon overlay just reflects it.

Comment: @w32sh If you can make the blue arrows disappear by unchecking the box in Advanced Attributes then it is just the shortcut that is compressed.