# Two blue arrows [compression?] on literally nearly everything

Tags: windows-10, compression

[image]I went to sleep, and now it seems that everything, from program folders to images, have blue arrows on the top right of their thumbnails. Naturally this has spooked me a little. Is there a way to mass reverse this, and are the integrity / quality of my files or images at risk?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: This is typically [caused by a Windows Update](https://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons/1381546#1381546) when you are relatively low on disk space, and you will find that there are already several questions about this within the Super User realm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, this is for a compressed folder:

[image]

[This link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/35552-change-remove-compression-blue-arrows-icons-windows-10-a.html)  explains the issue that Windows 10 supports compression for individual files and folders on NTFS volumes using NTFS compression.  It's nothing to be alarmed about, not a virus or anything..  This just allows you to shrink files to save space with the advantage to keep accessing your files as you would normally do without compression, and without the need to decompress files using extra software.

Perhaps you clicked on an option to do that, or a newly installed program had this feature to save some space or something.  Or you might have compressed them when right clicking on the drive and choosing to compress it and applied it to all subfolders and files:

[image]

You could reverse that by unchecking that option same way and applying it to all subfolders and files.  Or if they performance is the same or better and you want to keep it, but only change the icon, you can easily restore the "old-icon-look" through [the steps provided here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/35552-change-remove-compression-blue-arrows-icons-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I definitely didn't select anything along those lines so I'm confused how it's happened. Thanks though, now begins the long bar of uncompression : P