# Double blue arrow on every single one of my files, is that bad?

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop, icons, compression

I know it's caused by compression and I also know how to turn it off, all I'm asking is if this compression on files from Photoshop or Illustrator or even other folders is bad? I have no clue what I'm talking about, just curious If I should be worried or not.

[image: Screenshot]

It's in every single icon of my desktop not only these

I plan on removing these double arrows just worried if I should do anything about it? I've never had those arrows till yesterday. Is a compressed file the same as a "not compressed file without any double arrows"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two blue arrows at top right of icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to enable this compression on a large file (> 700 Mo), you will notice that it is going to slow you down significantly. If you are a professional, buying another drive will cost you less than having to deal with this every minute of every day.

Now, on my computer where no fancy compression is enabled, when I  save changes in Photoshop to a file which had been compressed, Windows doesn't re-compress the new file automagically. This is GOOD: imagine if you needed to update images imported in Indesign or in external smart objects. The compressed file loads fine in other Adobe applications, Bridge shows me the thumbnail...

I see no issue other than the compressing time and potentially the transferring time to another filesystem, which could be bad if you are often asked by clients to send open files.