# How to get back look of windows shortcuts? Updated

Tags: windows-10, icons

The modern look of windows10 icons is as follow on pictures. 
How to get rid of arrows on icons? 
UPD: as indicated in question [Two blue arrows at top right of icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons) i did uncheck of file archive property as well applied registry shell icons tweak. now i have  the look as follow: 
[image] with ugly blank square in place of arrows.
Enterprise windows 10x64 LTSC 1809 17763.379 where the registry branch shell icons does not exists.
[image: look after tweak]

***look before tweak***
 [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that i tried the fix from https://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons question. But my problem persists.

Comment: I also have this problem on other version of Windows 1809. Education, Enterprise and Pro version as well as Enterprise LTSC.

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick guide for your question.
check it out here https://mywindowshub.com/change-or-remove-double-blue-arrows-icon-on-compressed-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/

I hope it help :)

Comment: Thanks, i think this is good fix but not for actual build version of windows 10.