# A small number of unrelated programs suddenly have a Firefox icon. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-8, icons

4 programs suddenly show with Firefox icons in Windows 8. Not the data files, just the programs. For example pdfs show the correct pdf icon, but the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC program tile displays the Firefox icon. Likewise for Serif PagePlus. How do I fix this?

I tried deleting iconcache.db and then rebooting.

Update #1:
I did ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache which ended by shutting down.

I tried the technique here: http://www.winability.com/how-to-erase-icon-thumbnail-cache-windows-8/ and then rebooted.

All of the suggestions in the two articles mentioned in the comment seem to boil down to one of those three techniques above. The last one seemed most promising. None helped.

By the way, I navigated to Acrobat Reader DC under Program Files (x86) and it shows the correct icon there. If I launch from there I still get the wrong icon on the taskbar.

I have StartIsBack. I'm going to contact that vendor to see if the issue could be there somehow.

Update #2: I disabled StartIsBack, deleted iconcache*.db files and rebooted. Still shows wrong icon on taskbar and Windows tile.

Comment: Try some of the other solutions mentioned here and see if any fix it: http://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting If nothing works, try the Windows 8/8.1 solution here: https://neosmart.net/wiki/clear-icons-cache/

Comment: I tried each of those solutions, but still have the problem. (I updated the question with my results.)

Comment: Okay this one looks promising. They were having a very similar problem as you: http://ccm.net/forum/affich-519840-all-my-icons-change-to-internet-explorer