# Metro Dropbox icon instead of the regular one

Tags: windows-10, dropbox

Since a few weeks, my Dropbox icon in the start menu is looking like this:

[image]

My question is simple: is there a way to revert it to a standard icon?

I tried refreshing the icon cache, but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh Icon Cache Without Rebooting](http://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting)

Comment: Is this a desktop app or modern app?