# Generic icon instead of the Firefox logo icon in the context menu of its pinned to taskbar shortcut

Tags: windows-10, firefox, taskbar

I have FF 49.0.2 x64 in win 10 x64 v1607 build 14393 (i.e. with the Anniversary Update).

When Firefox is running, its icon is displayed on taskbar, as expected (i.e it's not a generic icon).
But, when I rightclick the Firefox shortcut which is pinned to the taskbar,
then, instead of the Firefox logo, a generic icon is displayed next to the "Mozilla Firefox" entry. Screenshot:
[image: img]
AS you may see, the "Frequent" and "Tasks" lists are present,
and all the "Frequent" entries have favicons.
Also, the relevant Firefox shortcut in Windows Start Menu has the FF logo icon, as expected. (screenshots:
[image: [1]] and
[image: [2]] )

The pinned shortcut itself supposedly gets its icon from `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`. Screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qbLH.jpg

This only happens when rightclicking on the FF pinned icon - all other pinned icons have their relevant icon when rightclicking them, including of Chrome browser:
[image: Chrome browser].

I have tried multiple times unpinning the shortcut from taskbar and then re-pin it,
as well as uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox, but didn't help.

In the above description I only have Firefox 49.0.2 installed.
If I uninstall Firefox 49 and then install Nightly 52 and launch it,
then -after a while- the Firefox (Nightly) logo icon is displayed in the context menu, as expected.

I believe that the issue might started after I uninstalled Firefox stable and installed Nightly (I had done this quite a few times). 
But I have uninstalled Nightly and currently have stable only.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the firefox shortcut with the generic icon, click on properties and check where it is getting the icon from by clicking on change icon.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have done this and the shortcut gets the icon from `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/6dM3aN4.jpg

Comment: So in properties you see the correct icon?
If so, you could try clearing the icon cache: http://superuser.com/a/499079/86594

Comment: Actually the method above to clear the cache is for pre Windows 8, the other answer from the same thread might work:
http://superuser.com/a/499083/86594

Comment: I followed this http://superuser.com/a/995680/298991 and the problem is fixed. Thanks a lot!