# How to clean up the Thumbnail or Icon Cache?

Tags: windows-10, thumbnails, thumbs.db

I'm trying to delete the thumbnail cache via the following command:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_*.db
```

I execute the statement as **administrator** and before of that I end the `explorer.exe`.

But I always get an access denied error.

What can I do about that? It's **Windows 10**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh Icon Cache Without Rebooting](http://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cleanmgr.exe` also Elevated. Either via the GUI or with /sageset /sagerun options. This may be automated via registry settings and a batch/script. [I just yesterday posted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534323/windows-update-cleanup-in-registry-editor/40537520#40537520)

Here's a reduced version of the PowerShell script

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
$SageSet = "StateFlags0099"
$Base = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\"
$Locations= @(
    "Thumbnail Cache"
)
ForEach($Location in $Locations) {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $($Base+$Location) -Name $SageSet -Type DWORD -Value 2 -ea silentlycontinue | Out-Null
}
# do the cleanup . have to convert the SageSet number
$Args = "/sagerun:$([string]([int]$SageSet.Substring($SageSet.Length-4)))"
Start-Process -Wait "$env:SystemRoot\System32\cleanmgr.exe" -ArgumentList $Args -WindowStyle Hidden
# Removw the Stateflags
ForEach($Location in $Locations)
{
    Remove-ItemProperty -Path $($Base+$Location) -Name $SageSet -Force -ea silentlycontinue | Out-Null
}
```