# Folder thumbnail / icon cache is broken

Tags: windows-7, icons, cache

I have read many questions here (such as [Refresh Icon Cache Without Rebooting](https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting)), tried methods like `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`, deleting all `Thumbs.db` hidden files, deleting the `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\IconCache.db` file, rebooting, etc. but this problems always comes back:

- When I browse my photos folders, everything is ok, but after a few folder navigation, I get the following display
- Note: once the problem arrives, every folder (even if it was correctly displayed with thumbnails previously) will be displayed like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can change the default Program for opening pictures. Because that Program deals with icons of photos.

If you are using Windows Photo Viewer , Delete and Install it again.or Just Install it again.

If That doesn't help there must be another built-in photo-viewer in Windows-7. just change default Programs in

```
Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs
```

I think that must help.