# why do .swift files in a windows file explorer folder have notepad's icon?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I look at one folder, all the .swift files incorrectly have Notepad icons.
But in another folder, they show up ok as Swift icons.

Comment: If you experience icon strangeness in Windows, the icon cache could be corrupt. You can find multiple ways to try and fix it [on this question](https://superuser.com/q/499078/219095).

Comment: There are other Explanations [[ (A) The files with incorrect Icons may be "someting.swift.txt" with the Extension hidden. (B) Those files may have Alternate Data Stream. (C) There may be a virus (D) ## ]] You should give more Details , Eg Explorer SnapShots , CMD DIR listings !!